# Assign a letter with a number

Tags: r, numbers, letter

How can I assign a letter into a number using Rstudio
for example
if A=1 C=2  G=3  T=4  ^= 5  !=6

Comment: Sorry, your code is not clear.  what is `^=5`

Comment: it's a character because I have a compressed sequence from  burrows wheeler transform (BWT) so am trying to decoding. the compressed sequence is !^GATTACA

Comment: it's a character because I have a compressed sequence from  burrows wheeler transform (BWT) so am trying to decoding. the compressed sequence is !^GATTACA. So when I use sort in R it puts the "^","!" at the beginning where I need it to be sorted at the end. so I thought assigning it to a numbers where I sort it the way I want

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example to learn how to write a better question, so  that we can help you with your problem.

Comment: am new in using this program, please can you help me am straggling a lot

Comment: Try ```x <- c(A=1, C=2, G=3, T=4, `^`= 5, `!`=6)```. Note the backticks in the special characters.

Comment: We're trying to help you ask a clear question. We can't help you with your question right now because we can't understand it. Please read Ricardo's link, and edit your question with the recommendations there.

Answer (score 4):

in base R: use the function `chartr`

```
x = "!^GATTACA"
chartr('ACGT^!', '123456', x)
[1] "653144121"
```

Comment: By far the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

As it's been pointed out in the coments, you need to give more context of your problem. In what format are your inputs and what is the expected output? See the link in the coments to lear how to improve.

But, assuming that you have a string saved onto a variable like:

```
x = "!^GATTACA"
```

You can replace each character using the `str_replace_all` of the `stringr` package:

```
install.packages("stringr") #if you don't have it installed yet
library(stringr)

str_replace_all(x, c("A"="1", "C"="2", "G"="3", "T"="4", "\\^"="5", "\\!"="6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that one of the following is what is asked for.

```r
x <- c(A=1, C=2, G=3, T=4, `^`= 5, `!`=6)
x
#> A C G T ^ ! 
#> 1 2 3 4 5 6

y <- "!^GATTACA"
s <- strsplit(y, "")[[1]]
i <- match(s, names(x))
i
#> [1] 6 5 3 1 4 4 1 2 1

s[c(3:length(s), 1, 2)]
#> [1] "G" "A" "T" "T" "A" "C" "A" "!" "^"

paste(s[c(3:length(s), 1, 2)], collapse = "")
#> [1] "GATTACA!^"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Note that if you `sort` the letters or indices you will loose the string `"GATTACA"`.

```r
sort(x[i])
#> A A A C G T T ^ ! 
#> 1 1 1 2 3 4 4 5 6

names(sort(x[i]))
#> [1] "A" "A" "A" "C" "G" "T" "T" "^" "!"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>